# Sitecore Throwing Exception During Indexing

Tags: indexing, upgrade

I've recently developed a problem in a local instance of `Sitecore (9.2, recently upgraded from 8.2)`. Upon trying to rebuild `sitecore_master_index` through the Indexing Manager, after processing for a time it throws an error :

[image: Error from Sitecore]

This is the exception as captured in Visual Studio :

[image: Error from Visual Studio]

I don't know what state this is leaving the index in, which interferes with work I'm doing which uses it, and since it's happening in external code I have no real insight into what might be causing it.  Does anyone know what might cause this, or know how to remedy it?  Thanks!

Comment: Is your solr version matching with your upgraded Sitecore version? Also do you have any custom index or OOTB?

Comment: We aren't using Solr at this time (still on Lucene).  We have a number of custom indexes, but I was only rebuilding sitecore_master_index when the exception was thrown.